# Can't get cd value in batch-file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to get current directory, but for some reasons I can't recieve it.

`for /f %%i in ('cd') do ( set log=%%i )`

`set log=%cd%`

I am trying these but nothing.
Could you explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: but you have the `%cd%` [variable](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html) ?

Comment: It works in shell but not in bat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
for /f %%i in ('cd') do ( set log=%%i &ECHO %%i)
ECHO log is %log%
set log=%cd%
ECHO now log is %log%
GOTO :EOF
```

Seems to work perfectly well for me. What do you mean by `I can't recieve it.` ?

Comment: It is really strange. It works for me as well but it doesn't separately

Comment: Threre was a stiupid mistake. Thanks a lot. Sorry for taking your time